# ggplot plotly unable to plot different lines with differing data arguments?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am unable to plot lines within plotly with different data arguments for the lines. Is this normal? Any workaround or bug fix for this?

```
y_data <- data.frame(x = c(-Inf, .5), y = c(10, 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x_data <- data.frame(x = c(.5, .5), y = c(-Inf, 10))

ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = y_data, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_line(data = x_data, aes(x,y))

ggplotly()
```

[image: ggplot]

[image: plotly]

Comment: Might be something wrong with `-Inf`. Replaced it with `0` then the lines appeared again

Comment: Often `-Inf` values are treated as `NA`. Since you got one `-Inf` in your `y` neither `ggplot2` nor `plotly` can plot the line

Comment: Ggplot2 did plot the line as in the image above, but I will keep that in mind.

Comment: How do I make it come from the edge of the map like in the ggplot example?

Comment: do you mean that: `y_data <- data.frame(x = c(0, .5), y = c(10, 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x_data <- data.frame(x = c(.5, .5), y = c(9.50, 10))` with `ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = y_data, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_line(data = x_data, aes(x,y)) + ylim(9.5, 10.5) + xlim(0, 1)` and `ggplotly()`?

Comment: Yea, doesn't really come to the edge

Comment: ok I know what you mean. `coord_cartesian`will help you with that. `y_data <- data.frame(x = c(-0.1, .5), y = c(10, 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`; 
`x_data <- data.frame(x = c(.5, .5), y = c(9.30, 10))`;
`ggplot() + geom_line(data = y_data, aes(x,y)) + geom_line(data = x_data, aes(x,y)) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(9.5, 10.5), xlim = c(0, 1)) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1))`; 
`ggplotly()`.